# How get date format in Django template

Tags: django, date

I am new to django. In my template I need the current date as date format, while the following code returns string:

```
<p>{% now "Y-m-d" as date %}</p>
```

where I want the date in format of 2018-12-17 as a date not string. Is there anyway to do that?

thnaks

Comment: or you can use moment.js to get date in required format if you are not sending date from views

Comment: I do not want to add extra libraries, and sending time in view is my current approach which is not our preferred way..tnx

Comment: To make the current date/time available in a template as a variable (`date` or `datetime` instead of `str` as shown in this answer) you can find a few options in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52336898/9225671) I wrote some time ago.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use filters built into django

```
{{ value|date:"D d M Y" }}
```

find more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#date)

Comment: I have a custom filter which accepts only date format. would you tell me more specifically how to use that? I have read the link you said but I didn't get how to do that. Suppose my filter name is CustomDateFilter and what I want is {{  date|CustomDateFilter }} that I need date be in date format, while 'now' returns strings only

Comment: In the template-tag named **CustomDateFilter**, add an argument named **value** to receive the date value and change it to the format you want. For eg,  `def lower(value):                                                                                             
    return value.lower()`

Comment: yeah I believe that is the only way..thanks @VijeshVenugopal

Comment: Just to add more info to an already good answer: If you ever need the current date/time in a template as a variable (`date` or `datetime` instead of `str` as produced by the built-in filters and tags) you can find a few options in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52336898/9225671) I wrote some time ago.

Comment: when I add {{ value|date:"D d M Y" }} to my template nothing shows. Do I need to load anything first?